# Does the same Dockerfile always produce identical image though different machine?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have done some research about the OverlayFS and know the docker image is composed of layers.

In the real world, docker image could either be built through the Jenkins server, or built on my laptop.

Here is a dockerfile sample.

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

**Question1: Using the same dockerfile, do different hosts produce the same image with identical layers, layer.DiffID and image Id?**

**Question2: If different host produces different docker images, how do we share the tag or any layer cache under the hood?**

Imagine the following scenario

1. Bob build an image based on the dockerfile in his laptop and tag the image as `v1`.
2. Bob pushes the image to the Docker registry.
3. Alice changes the docker file, rebuilds an image in her Macbook, then tag the image as `v2`.
4. Alice push the image to the Docker registry.

Will Alice's build just add a new layer to Bob's image or totally overwrite Rob's image?

Comment: No they don't. Your example Dockerfile, for instance, contains the statement `COPY . .` which copies files from the host to the image. Depending on what's in the host directory, the images can/will be different.

Comment: It depends on how you have written your DockerFile. If you have any COPY commands to copy files from host machine(which is always not recommended) then you end up in machine specific image.
Usual best practice is to build the image in build servers like Azure dev ops (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/) which can be used by your team. The trick is to write DockerFile not to have any host file dependencies

Comment: reddit: Does building docker images on different machines prevent sharing the layers? https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/j7evu2/does_building_docker_images_on_different_machines/

Comment: Docker: Specifying external cache sourceshttps://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-external-cache-sources